# Which ways of communicating with a controller are real-time safe?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, real-time, service, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm developing a custom controller, which in the end should run in a real-time environment.
Hence, I would like to ensure, that what I develop is real-time safe. More specific, I would like to know, which possibilities there are to communicate with a controller from outside of the real-time environment.
For my use case, the communication itself has not to be real-time safe, but it should not make the controller go out of real-time.

I would be very happy, if somebody could provide better insight into that topic!

Let's start with what I found out up till now. During my work, I saw a couple of possible ways for communication, namely subscribers/publishers, service calls and "normal" (set-)functions providing the ability to change class members of the controller.

Which of them run "where" in terms of "in real-time" or "in non real-time"?
One example: In the tutorials there are service calls ([realtime_joint_controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Communicating%20with%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)) and normal set-functions ([JointVelocityController](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController), [source code](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/robot_mechanism_controllers/html/joint__velocity__controller_8cpp_source.html)) used to changed the values of class members . Are both ways real-time safe and if so, why?
Another example: I read about the special variant of the ROS publisher, which is real-time safe ([realtime_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/realtime_tools)). Does the description in the package summary imply, that a normal ROS subscriber is not real-time safe?

Let me add, that I am no real-time expert. So, I would appreciate simple explanations! :-)

Thanks a lot for your help!

:-) Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9423/which-ways-of-communicating-with-a-controller-are-real-time-safe?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Marcus,

The `update()`, `starting()`, and `stopping()` calls of your controller are the only methods which execute in the realtime thread.  Everything else (including `init()` and any ROS callbacks) executes in a different, concurrent, non-realtime thread.

Normal ROS publishers are absolutely NOT realtime safe.  The `RealtimePublisher` in realtime_tools is realtime safe.

*Edit: forgot that `starting()` and `stopping()` both run in realtime.*

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2011-03-25**:
Subscribers, services, timers, parameter updates.  All of these run in non-realtime.  Only `update()`, `starting()`, and `stopping()` run in realtime.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2011-03-25**:
"[...] any ROS callbacks) [...]" i guess that includes subscribers and services as well?